# Consuming web service in C# -List

Tags: c#, java, list, generics, object

score#UPDATED# This probably sounds pretty dumb but I've been stuck on this problem for three days now! 
I am new to C#.

I am trying to consume a web service in C#. I managed to consume the web service in Java with the following lines of code:

```
            List x = new ArrayList<Score>();

            x = topScores();

            System.out.println("x" + x.size());

            System.out.println("TOP SCORES:");
            for (Object o : x) {
                Score s1 = (Score) o;
                System.out.println(s1.getScore());

            }
```

I need to display a list of scores but can't seem to figure it out in C#.  Here is where I am stuck in C#:

```
           List<object[]> list = new List<score[]>();
```

I have tried loads of different variations of declaring collections but can't get past this.  I think I know how to iterate through a list but I can't get past declaring it. Here is my error message:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type `System.Collections.Generic.List<score>' to `System.Collections.Generic.List<object>'
```

If I change the declaration to :

```
List<score> list = new List<score>();
list = service.TopScores();
```

I get the same error but this time I get a message saying:

```
"Object[] TopScores()"
```

What is the C# equivalent of my Java snippet? I'd really appreciate any help or suggestions! Thank you for your time!

Comment: Try `List<Score> list = new List<Score>();`

Comment: It is obvious, in that the reason why you can't convert between the two is that `List<object[]>` is not a supertype of `List<score[]>`. Not even in Java's generics implementation, although Java will let you get around that with hideously not-type-safe code. (There are probably many, many questions on SO with an explanation why that's the case.) Why can't you just use the same type on both sides of the statement?

Comment: Hey lads! thanks for the help! unfortunately I still haven't been able to fix it.  If I change the list to "List<Score> list = new List<Score>();" and then try to call the webservice "list = service.TopScores();"..I get the same error! Now I am getting the help message saying "Object[] TopScores()".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your help...I figured it out...

```
        LoginService service = new LoginService();
        List<score> listA = new List<score>();

        object[] array = listA.ToArray();
        array = service.TopScores();
```

Answer (score 2):

The List<> class is in a category of collections called Generics, which allows you to create an array of strongly-typed objects.  .  The List part implies an array, so you don't need to declare the type as an array as well.  Instead of `List<object[]>`, you should just do `List<object>`.  You also can't change the data type of the list. If you want to create a list of `Score` you should just do.

```
List<Score> scores = new List<Score>();
```

then you could populate the list with scores like

```
Score newScore = new Score();
scores.Add(newScore);
```

or whatever

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't need to create a `List<object>` because your code always knows that the elements of the list are of type `Score`. You can do this instead

```
List<Score> list = new List<Score>(); // Not really necessary because you assign it a different value in the next line.

list = topScores().Select(o => o.ToString()).ToList();

...

System.Console.WriteLine("x{0}", list.Length);

System.Console.WriteLine("TOP SCORES:");
foreach (var score in list) {
    System.Console.WriteLine(score.GetScore());
}
```

However if you really want to create a `List<object>` from a `List<string>` the easiest way to do that is this:

```
List<string> stringList = ...
List<object> objectList = stringList.ToList<object>();
```

Comment: Hey lads! thanks for the help! unfortunately I still haven't been able to fix it.  If I change the list to "List<Score> list = new List<Score>();" and then try to call the webservice "list = service.TopScores();"..I get the same error! Now I am getting the help message saying "Object[] TopScores()".

Comment: @DavidDonnellan You can use Linq to convert the `objects[]` to a `List<string>`. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the same type when declaring this list.

```
List<score> list = new List<score>();
```

then

```
    foreach(Score score in list)
    {
    //do something
    }
```

Comment: "You need to have the same type" not true. You could instantiate a subclass of `List<>`. `List<score> list = new MyCustomList()` works fine.

Comment: But surely in this instance using object and score isn't working?

Comment: Yes of course. Your code works, I just wanted to clarify the wording to avoid any potential confusion.

Comment: I changed A to this, I knew what I meant, haha.